# Git pull unable to lock ref, permanent solution?

Tags: git, github, repository

I am working on a huge repository and we are total 900 people who are working on the same, creating a new branch for each feature/bug/hotfix (lets call it "custom branch") we are working on and deleting the same after successful testing and merging it into the mainline branch(Total: 5), which leads us to the errors like `unable to lock local ref`.

Our repository structure is in following format for staging:

```
mainline-level-1
                 -> mainline-level-2
                                    -> mainline-level-3
                                                       -> mainline-level-4
                                                                          -> mainline-level-5
```

Everyone in the organization is facing a issue of git pull showing some error related to **unable to lock local ref.** which can be and being addressed by us using some handy commands like `git remote prune origin` OR `git gc --prune=now` OR `git pull origin mainline-level-1` but these are long shots for us when it comes to servers where we are doing git pull and it is not really possible to run those commands on server(including automating them) due to some reasons.

So, I went out of the box to see if we can have those errors removed. as we are not checking out any custom branch on the server side and all we need is our mainline branches there.

I tried adding the git config to fetch only the mainline branch for our repository. so after adding config changes git config for my local repository looks like:

```
[foo]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:gods/foo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/mainline-level-1:refs/remotes/origin/mainline-level-1
        fetch = +refs/heads/mainline-level-2:refs/remotes/origin/mainline-level-2
        fetch = +refs/heads/mainline-level-3:refs/remotes/origin/mainline-level-3
        fetch = +refs/heads/mainline-level-4:refs/remotes/origin/mainline-level-4
        fetch = +refs/heads/mainline-level-5:refs/remotes/origin/mainline-level-5
[branch "mainline-level-1"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/mainline-level-1
```

**SO LET'S GET BACK TO THE QUESTIONS HERE**

1. Is it recommended to have such config?
2. Will it create any further issues on the repository?(Addressing both local/remote)
3. Is it possible to have a local to have such config(for developers), so that we don't face the issue.
4. Can I configure the git to clone it this way?
   Note: currently I'm following the flow to achieve intended state on the repository:
   `initialize empty repo`->`add a remote`->`add config changes`->`do the git pull`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is it recommended?  I don't know: it seems like this would depend on who is doing the recommendations.
2. Will it create further issues?  No, but it won't solve them either.
3. Is it possible to have such a configuration?  Yes, of course, you demonstrated that yourself.
4. Can you configure `git clone` to do this?  Not precisely, no: `git clone --single-branch` gets close though, and after doing that, you can use `git remote set-branches --add` to add the four remaining branches, so that instead of a single-branch clone, you have a five-branch clone.

Your best bet, though, would be to figure out *why* your systems are doing this.  That's usually a sign of running multiple parallel `git fetch` operations on a single repository (don't do that!).

It sounds like you have multiple users sharing a single Git repository in which they try to do work.  Don't do that!  Git repositories are meant to be private to each developer.

Comment: I have tried it on the local repository this solution is completely tried and tested it works for those errors.
and regarding the repository privatization the repo we are talking about is shared by organization in through out the teams, so negative on that we can break up the repository for each team that will harm the main purpose of creating it.

Comment: I would like you opinion on first question in detail. and about the second question it is solved as I mentioned but it is solved only for that particular clone. also I would like to know your view on this as well like why you are saying it won't solve the problem? on to the third point i meant to ask is it possible to hold this configurations reliable in long run for purpose of non-failure pulls? as per my knowledge we can keep this configurations until there is no change in those branch names on to the remotes end. please correct me if im wrong or missing something. @torek

Comment: I just got curious about the time consumption of a git pull
`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
having this in my config vs having the specified branches config does impacts that time taken for `git pull`?

if it does what will be the optimum configuration for the fastest git pull? (please consider the work flow i have mentioned above)

Comment: For the recommendation question: I myself stand firmly in the middle of "neither recommended nor discouraged". Everyone needs to decide on this situation for themselves. It's a *supported* workflow due to `--single-branch` and `git remote set-branches --add`, so it's not going to break. It comes at the cost of a more complex original clone and needing to understand what you're doing.

Comment: As for time consumption: this depends. Note that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command* and the *second* command may be the slow one, in which case changing the amount of time spent in `git fetch` may be irrelevant. (The operation of the second command isn't affected by the single-branch-ness, assuming sensible use of single-branch-ness.) The *fetch* step could run faster *if* the other branches have a significant number of commits with large enough files that this results in significantly less overall data transfer. Usually, it would probably be immeasurable.